# what's about go type and point syntax

Tags: go, type-conversion

the dmeo code

```
package listing12_9

import (
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
)

type SpinLock int32

func (s *SpinLock) Lock() {
    for !atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32((*int32)(s), 0, 1) {
        runtime.Gosched()
    }
}

func (s *SpinLock) Unlock() {
    atomic.StoreInt32((*int32)(s), 0)
}

func NewSpinLock() sync.Locker {
    var lock SpinLock
    return &lock
}
```

what's about `atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32((*int32)(s), 0, 1)` syntax，(*int) and (s) mean?

Comment: `(*int32)(s)` converts `s`, whose type is `*SpinLock`, to an `*int32`.  For more about type conversions in Go, see the relevant section of the language specification: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have defined a type here:

```
type SpinLock int32
```

but you're going to call a method in atomic package with this spec:

```
func CompareAndSwapInt32(addr *int32, old, new int32) (swapped bool)
```

so to send your variable **s** with type **SpinLock** to **CompareAndSwapInt32** method, you have to say to compiler that the **s** can be used as **int32**, it's called **type conversion**, in golang we do this kind of job like this:

```
convertedValue := TargetType(variable)
```

but in the **Learn Concurrent Programming with Go** book it uses the old fashioned way of casting variable **s** from type  ***SpinLock** to ***int32**, the more modern way of doing this could be:

```
type SpinLock int32

func (s SpinLock) Lock() {
    castedS := int32(s)
    for !atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32(&castedS, 0, 1) {
        runtime.Gosched()
    }
}

func (s SpinLock) Unlock() {
    castedS := int32(s)
    atomic.StoreInt32(&castedS, 0)
    atomic.StoreInt32(&castedS, 0)
}
```